# Context Api is returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here I have declared a basic prototype for my context store and when I try to use this store it is returning undefined even though I double checked the syntax so someone can please help why its returning undefined:

**Store:**

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext("Default");

export const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  const loginHandler = () => {
    console.log("Login Handler");
  };
  const logoutHandler = () => {
    console.log("Logout Handler");
  };

  const contextValue = {
    token: "false",
    loging: loginHandler,
    logout: logoutHandler,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContext;
```

**App:**

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import Main from "./components/Main";
import "./App.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store/DataStore";
import AuthContext from "./store/AuthStore";

const App = () => {
  const ctx = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {console.log(ctx.token)}
      <Main />
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Is the `<AuthContextProvider>` farther up the component tree than `<App>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your **App** component by the **AuthContextProvider** component.

**index.js**

```
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthContextProvider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

**App.js**

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import AuthContext from "./store/authStore";

const App = () => {
  const ctx = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(ctx.token)}
      <p>Hello</p>
      {console.log(ctx)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**authStore.js**

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext("Default");

export const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  const loginHandler = () => {
    console.log("Login Handler");
  };
  const logoutHandler = () => {
    console.log("Logout Handler");
  };

  const contextValue = {
    token: "false",
    loging: loginHandler,
    logout: logoutHandler,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContext;
```

Answer (score 1):

1.) Your default value for the context is the string "Default" (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext)

2.) You are reading the context before using the provider you defined, so you are never setting the context value to your object. (see second paragraph of https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext)

The result is you are reading the `token` property off the string `"Default"`...which would be undefined. Linked is an example using your provider and how it changes context in components further down the tree. https://playcode.io/980421